# Spacy regex over entities

Tags: expression, spacy, named

How can you use in Spacy v2 the usual regex functionality but over named entities and POS?
It seems that the full syntax of the Matcher's patterns is not available.
Only scattered examples like the following are available

```
[{'LOWER': 'facebook'}, {'LEMMA': 'be'}, {'POS': 'ADV', 'OP': '*'}, {'POS': 'ADJ'}]
```

What I need is to allow for an arbitrary number of repetions of a group. 
In the example below assume color as an entity and I only know Red is a color.

```
"Red, green and black" , "Red, white, green and black"
```

I need to recognize green, black, white as color entities as well since I know red is a color entity and whatever follows it by comma is also a color.

Atm i do it like this but it works only for a certain number of commas, not for an arbitrary number:

```
 pattern = [{'ent_type': 'Color'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'CCONJ'},{'POS': 'NOUN'}]
 matcher.add('commas', add_event_skill, pattern)
```

In a more advanced version of my question, red would be allowed to be in any position of the sentencne, not only the first.